# Prove $\max_i w_i$ is a convex function.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

$f(w)=\max_i(w_i)$ where $w$ is in $\mathbb R^n$.

I know that norms are convex. And this looks equivalent to the infinity norm except there's no absolute value around $w_i$. This is where I'm stuck. I also know that the max of convex functions is itself convex. But I'm not sure how to prove each $w_i$ as convex.

Comment: $w_i = <(0, 0,.., 1, …, 0), w>$ where $1$ is at the $i’th$ index. Therefore it is linear.

Comment: Please don't repost questions. If questions are poorly received like your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4551803/prove-max-i-w-i-is-a-convex-function), it is expected that you edit them, rather than post another copy. Although, it is worth noting the difference when you put the context into the body of the question, rather than leaving it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The function that maps $w=(w_1, \ldots, w_n)$ to its $i$th member $w_i$ is
$$
f_i(w):=w_i
$$
This function is a linear function of $w$, hence it is convex. More explicitly, if $w$ and $w'$ are in $\mathbb R^n$ and $\alpha\in (0,1)$, then
$$f_i(\alpha w + (1-\alpha)w') = (\alpha w + (1-\alpha)w')_i =\alpha w_i + (1-\alpha)w_i'
= \alpha f_i(w) + (1-\alpha)f_i(w'),$$ so each $f_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ satisfies the definition of convexity.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that we have $t \in [0, 1]$ and we have $w, x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

For simplicity, write $z = tw + (1 - t) x$. The goal is to show that $f(z) \leq t f(w) + (1 - t) f(x)$.

Take the $j$ such that $f(z) = z_j$ (that is, the $j$ for which $z_j$ is maximised). Then we see that $f(z) = z_j = t w_j + (1 - t) x_j$. Now $w_j \leq \max_i w_i = f(z)$, and similarly, $x_j \leq \max_i x_i = f(x)$. Therefore, we have $t w_j \leq t f(w)$, and $(1 - t) x_j \leq (1 - t) f(x)$. Then $t w_j + (1 - t) x_j \leq t f(w) + (1 - t) f(x)$, as required.